# How can I properly set the gas / value for sending a transaction with web3.js?

Tags: web3js, gas, sendrawtransaction

My code is:

```
function sendEth(fromAddress, secret, toAddress, amount) {
  let params = {
    to: toAddress,
    from: fromAddress,
    value: web3.utils.toWei(amount + '', 'ether')
  };
  console.log(params);

  return Promise.all([web3.eth.estimateGas(params), web3.eth.getGasPrice()])
    .then((response) => {
      const estimatedGas = response[0];
      const gasPrice = response[1];
      params.gas = estimatedGas;
      params.gasPrice = web3.utils.toWei(1.1 * gasPrice + ''); // Use 10% more gas than recommended
      params.value = web3.utils.toWei(params.value - params.gas * params.gasPrice + '');

      return web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(params, secret);
    })
    .then((signedTx) => {
      return web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);
    });
}
```

But I get an error:

```
 Error: while converting number to string, invalid number value '-1.1549989999999999e+23', should be a number matching (^-?[0-9.]+).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript doesn't support numbers with arbitrary precision that are required when doing calculation with ether values (ether has 18 decimals!).

Web3 v1.0 it will wrap numeric values in [bn.js](https://github.com/indutny/bn.js) objects. Instead of using regular mathematical operators (+, -, *, /, etc) you have to use [arithmetic methods](https://github.com/indutny/bn.js#arithmetics) from bn.js:

Instead of `a * b + c` you have to do `a.mul(b).add(c)`. To convert to bn.js format web3 provides function [`web3.utils.toBN()`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#tobn).

For example your gas calculations can be done like this:

```
params.gasPrice = web3.utils.toBN(gasPrice)
    .mul(web3.utils.toBN(11))
    .div(web3.utils.toBN(10));  // gasPrice * 1.1

params.value = web3.utils.toBN(params.value)
    .sub(
        web3.utils.toBN(params.gas).mul(
            web3.utils.toBN(params.gasPrice)
        )
    );     // value - (gas * gasPrice)
```

Comment: There's no way to do `times 1.1` directly?